# How to unlock account across all sites immediately

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows

We recently implmented a way to allow users to unlock accounts themselves after too many invalid password attempts. It is working great, but we are having an issue with replicating account unlocks across sites (with Active Directory on Windows Server 2008 R2). Lockouts replicate to all domain controllers immediately but unlocks only unlock immediately in the site they are unlocked and then take 15 minutes to replicate to the other sites.

I have been searching for a setting that would allow unlocks to be replicated across all sites immedaitely but I am not havning any luck. Does anyone know how to replicate unlocks immediately?

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 4):

By default, account unlock is not urgently replicated.
You can configure Urgent Replication for the Unlock Account operation:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772726%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#w2k3tr_repup_how_huzs

Comment: a couple things the fastest you can update items that are urgent is 15 minutes, secondly I don't think unlock events are urgent, just locking events.

Comment: >the fastest you can update items that are urgent is 15 minutes
Are you sure about that?

Comment: haven't needed to make this change before so I don't know for sure.

Comment: I guess I should ask do you see anything in the doc that suggests it could be less then 15 minutes?

Comment: _Urgent replication is implemented immediately by using RPC/IP to notify replication partners that changes have occurred on a source domain controller._

Comment: yep I was wrong confused this with lds which in this case is notthe case!

Answer (score 2):

If you have high-speed WAN connectivity between your sites (like T1 or higher) and you're not constantly replicating *tons* of data in AD, you can [enable change notify](http://blogs.technet.com/b/qzaidi/archive/2010/09/23/enable-change-notifications-between-sites-how-and-why.aspx) on your site links in AD. This will cause replication between sites to happen as quickly as intra-site replication (a few seconds). This changes the "pull" model of inter-site replication to a "push" model.

Note that this will cause *all* replication to happen between sites instantly, not just lockouts and it will disable the compression that is normally used on inter-site replications. That said, *most* modern ADs are good candidates for this with 10Mb+ WAN connections being quite common.

Answer (score 0):

hmm you could do a powershell command and run a remote ps sessions to each AD site and have them issue the unlock, haven't tried this but it will work.

Comment: alternatively you could make your unlock application site aware.

Comment: The program is site aware, but we have some people doing remote desktop into other sites... when they get locked out in the distant site, it takes 15 minutes to replicate back to the site they are originating the request from.

Comment: I'll look into doing that with powershell, but I'm not completely sure how I would initiate that script for a particular user. The program unlocking is 3rd party software that doesn't have any way to tie into it.